# c# Compare arduino serial with string

Tags: c#, arduino, serial-port

I am trying to get serial data from my Arduino and compare it with a string in c#

the arduino code waits for a switch and then sends the corresponding string
along with it,
eg switch 5 make it print "5on" when on and "5off" when off

i know that arduino `Serial.println("");` prints with a new line, so in c# I made the string a multi line string with `@` and did a new line but still with this it won't compare.

I can get the serial data into C# but I can't compare it

Arduino Code:

```
  if(digitalRead(14) == 1){
    pin13 = 1;
  }
  else if(digitalRead(14) == 0){
    pin13 = 0;
  }

  if(digitalRead(5) == 1){
    Serial.println("5on");
  }
  else if(digitalRead(5) == 0){
    Serial.println("5off");
  }

  if(digitalRead(2) == 1){
    Serial.println("2on");
  }
  else if(digitalRead(2) == 0){
    Serial.println("2off");
  }


  if(digitalRead(12) == 1){
    Serial.println("12on");
  }
  else if(digitalRead(12) == 0){
    Serial.println("12off");
  }


  if(digitalRead(4) == 1){
    Serial.println("4on");    
  }
  else if(digitalRead(4) == 0){
    Serial.println("4off");    
  }
```

C# Code:

```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Text;
  using System.Threading.Tasks;
  using System.IO.Ports;
  using System.Threading;

namespace test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //SerialPort port = new SerialPort("COM3", 115200);
            SerialPort port = new SerialPort("COM4", 9600);
            port.Open();
            while (!port.IsOpen)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(".");
            }
            if (port.IsOpen)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("CONNECTED");
            }
            int switch5onallow=0;
            while (true)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(100);
                string a = port.ReadExisting();
                Console.WriteLine(a);
                string switch5on = @"5on
";
                string switch5off = @"5off
";
                string switch2on = @"2on
";
                string switch2off = @"2off
";
                string switch12on = @"12on
";
                string switch12off = @"12off
";
                string switch4on = @"4on
";
                string switch4off = @"4off
";


                if (a == switch5on)
                {
                    //System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@".\AHK\5on.ahk");
                    Console.WriteLine("switch5on");
                    switch5onallow = 0;
                }
                else if (a == switch5off)
                {
                    //System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@".\AHK\5off.ahk");
                    Console.WriteLine("switch5off");
                    switch5onallow = 1;
                }
                else if (a == switch2on)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@".\AHK\2on.ahk");
                }
                else if (a == switch2off)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@".\AHK\2off.ahk");
                }
                else if (a == switch12on)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@".\AHK\12on.ahk");
                }
                else if (a == switch12off)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@".\AHK\12off.ahk");
                }
                else if (a == switch4on)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@".\AHK\4on.ahk");
                }
                else if (a == switch4off)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@".\AHK\4off.ahk");
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Please add the code directly into the question, not everybody has access to off-site resources and external links can expire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options:

First option is just **Trim** the input string when you read it in

```
const string SwitchOn5 = "5on";

string a = port.ReadExisting().Trim();
if (a.Equals(SwitchOn5))        // will return true
```

Second option is instead of trying of comparing whole string, you can just do a **StartsWith** check (first is probably better):

```
const string SwitchOn5 = "5on";

if (a.StartsWith(SwitchOn5))    // will return true
```